# How to refresh a SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable that creates an ARView, when a virtual object is attached to its mesh?

Tags: ios, arkit, realitykit

I am experimenting with an AR app. I am trying to do the following:
The iOS device displays the real scene by an `ARView`, and the `ARView` creates a mesh.
Whenever the mesh is updated, I want to find the vertex closest to the camera, and attach a virtual object to it (after deleting a possibly previously attached object).

I am not sure if my current code is correct, but it seems that it does what I have described above. If I move the device, the displayed mesh is updated. When a new closest vertex is found, it toggles a state var `refreshToggle` in the `MainView`, and I expected that the updated mesh is displayed together with the virtual object. But the virtual object is not shown, and I don't understand why.

Here is my code. I am sorry that it is so long, but I am not sure what to omit.
Any help is welcome!

```
struct MainView : View {
    @State private var refreshToggle = false // Toggled, when a new closest anchor is found
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer(refreshToggle: $refreshToggle).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var refreshToggle: Bool
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options = []
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.occlusion) // Turn on occlusion from the scene reconstruction's mesh.
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.physics) // Turn on physics for the scene reconstruction's mesh.
        arView.debugOptions.insert(.showSceneUnderstanding) // Display a debug visualization of the mesh.
        arView.renderOptions = [.disablePersonOcclusion, .disableDepthOfField, .disableMotionBlur] // Disable not required render options
        arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator($refreshToggle)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {
        @Binding var refreshToggle: Bool
        var model: ModelEntity
        
        init(_ refreshToggle: Binding<Bool>) {
            self._refreshToggle = refreshToggle
            
            // Create a cube model
            let mesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.1, cornerRadius: 0.005)
            let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .gray, roughness: 0.15, isMetallic: true)
            model = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
        }
        
        func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
            var closestAnchor: ARAnchor? = nil
            for anchor in anchors {
                if let meshAnchor = anchor as? ARMeshAnchor {
                    let meshGeometry = meshAnchor.geometry
                    let vertices = meshGeometry.vertices

                    // Search for the vertex closest to the camera and place there a virtual marker object
                    let nrVertices = vertices.count
                    var closestVertex = SIMD3<Float>(x: 0, y: .infinity, z: 0) 
                    for i in 0 ..< nrVertices {
                        let nextVertex = meshGeometry.vertex(at: UInt32(i))
                        if nextVertex.y < closestVertex.y {
                            closestVertex = nextVertex
                            if closestAnchor?.identifier != meshAnchor.identifier {
                                // A new closest anchor has been found. Remove a virtual marker object
                                if let closestAnchor = closestAnchor {
                                    let anchor = AnchorEntity(anchor: closestAnchor)
                                    anchor.children.remove(model)
                                }
                            }           
                            closestAnchor = meshAnchor
                        }
                    }           
                    
                    // If a closest vertex was found, attach a virtual object to it
                    if let closestAnchor = closestAnchor {
                        let anchor = AnchorEntity(anchor: closestAnchor)
                        anchor.children.append(model)
                        refreshToggle = !refreshToggle // Let ARViewContainer redisplay the real scene with the mesh and a virtual object attached to the closest anchor
                    }
                } // if an ARMeshAnchor was found
            } // for all anchors
        } // session didUpdate anchors
    } // coordinator
    
}

extension ARMeshGeometry { // See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/armeshgeometry/3516924-vertices
    func vertex(at index: UInt32) -> SIMD3<Float> {
        assert(vertices.format == MTLVertexFormat.float3, "Expected three floats (twelve bytes) per vertex.")
        let vertexPointer = vertices.buffer.contents().advanced(by: vertices.offset + (vertices.stride * Int(index)))
        let vertex = vertexPointer.assumingMemoryBound(to: SIMD3<Float>.self).pointee
        return vertex
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with your code is most likely that SwiftUI is not refreshing the UIViewRepresentable type when you toggle the refreshToggle state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, although I don't understand it (no experience in Computer Graphics).
After the closest mesh anchor has been found, one has to create an `AnchorEntity`.
In this entity, one has to set the `anchoring` property with an `AnchoringComponent` initialized with an appropriate `AnchoringComponent.Target`. Only then is the virtual object rendered in the scene.

The following code works for me, and is based on some valuable info, the answer of KFDoom (+1), a [blog of Ethan Saadia](https://ethansaadia.medium.com/ray-casting-in-realitykit-9288be5c3e2c), and a [tutorial of Ralf Ebert](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios/realitykit-wuerfel-tutorial/).

Here is the updated code in case somebody wants to play with it.
The transform in `.world(transform: transform)` has been taken from a different version and turned out to be useful.

```
import ARKit
import RealityKit
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView()
        
        // Configure the ARView to generate a mesh
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options = []
        
        // Turn on occlusion from the scene reconstruction's mesh.
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.occlusion)
        
        // Turn on physics for the scene reconstruction's mesh.
        arView.environment.sceneUnderstanding.options.insert(.physics)
        
        // Display a debug visualization of the mesh.
        arView.debugOptions.insert(.showSceneUnderstanding)
        
        // For performance, disable render options that are not required for this app.
        arView.renderOptions = [.disablePersonOcclusion, .disableDepthOfField, .disableMotionBlur]
        arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        // Handle ARSession events via delegate
        context.coordinator.arView = arView
        arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, ARSessionDelegate {
        var model: ModelEntity
        weak var arView: ARView?
        
        override init() {
            // Create a cube model
            let boxMesh = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.1, cornerRadius: 0.005)
            let material = SimpleMaterial(color: .gray, roughness: 0.15, isMetallic: true)
            model = ModelEntity(mesh: boxMesh, materials: [material])

            super.init()
        }

        func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
            var closestAnchor: ARAnchor? = nil
            guard let arView = arView else { return }
            
            // Create a single AnchorEntity instance
            var anchorEntity: AnchorEntity?
            
            for anchor in anchors {
                if let meshAnchor = anchor as? ARMeshAnchor {
                    let meshGeometry = meshAnchor.geometry
                    let vertices = meshGeometry.vertices
                    
                    // For debugging, we search for the vertex closest to the camera and place there a virtual marker object

                    let nrVertices = vertices.count
                    var closestVertex = SIMD3<Float>(x: 0, y: .infinity, z: 0) 
                    for i in 0 ..< nrVertices {
                        let nextVertex = meshGeometry.vertex(at: UInt32(i))
                        // The frontmost vertex has the largest z value, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/organizing_a_scene_with_nodes
                        if nextVertex.z > closestVertex.z {
                            closestVertex = nextVertex
                            if closestAnchor?.identifier != meshAnchor.identifier {
                                // A new closest anchor has been found. Remove the virtual marker object if it exists.
                                // If an anchorEntity already exists, remove it from the ARView's scene
                                if let existingAnchor = anchorEntity {
                                    existingAnchor.removeFromParent()
                                }
                            }           
                            closestAnchor = meshAnchor
                        }
                    }           
                    
                } // if an ARMeshAnchor found
            } // for all anchors
            
            // If a closest vertex was found, attach a virtual object to it
            if let closestAnchor = closestAnchor {
                // Create a new AnchorEntity and attach the model to it
                anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: closestAnchor)
                let transform = simd_float4x4([[0.96475136, 0.0, 0.26316252, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [-0.26316252, 0.0, 0.9647514, 0.0], [0.16189954, -0.25364277, -0.22894737, 1.0]])
                let anchoring = AnchoringComponent(.world(transform: transform))
                anchorEntity!.anchoring = anchoring
                anchorEntity!.addChild(model)
                arView.scene.anchors.append(anchorEntity!)
            }
        } // session didUpdate anchors
    } // coordinator
}

extension ARMeshGeometry { // See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/armeshgeometry/3516924-vertices
    func vertex(at index: UInt32) -> SIMD3<Float> {
        assert(vertices.format == MTLVertexFormat.float3, "Expected three floats (twelve bytes) per vertex.")
        let vertexPointer = vertices.buffer.contents().advanced(by: vertices.offset + (vertices.stride * Int(index)))
        let vertex = vertexPointer.assumingMemoryBound(to: SIMD3<Float>.self).pointee
        return vertex
    }
}

#Preview {
    MainView()
}
```

Comment: Added explanation above.

Comment: Sorry couldn't get to this sooner--work day got ahead of me

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: Explanation for code below
>
> I'm glad that the solution worked for you!
>
> Just to clarify a bit for those who might be unfamiliar with this
> code, what this is doing is generating an augmented reality view using
> Apple's ARKit, RealityKit, and SwiftUI. ARKit is Apple's framework for
> creating augmented reality experiences, RealityKit is a Swift-based
> framework for creating 3D content for augmented reality, and SwiftUI
> is Apple's framework for declarative user interface construction.
>
> The main task here is to locate the "closest" ARAnchor (a 3D point in
> the augmented reality space) among all detected ARAnchors. The closest
> ARAnchor is the one that has a vertex (point in 3D space) with the
> largest z-coordinate (since in SceneKit, which underlies ARKit, the
> z-axis points from the camera towards the scene).
>
> Once the closest ARAnchor is found, it is used to create an
> AnchorEntity, which is a RealityKit entity that connects virtual
> content with a real-world object or position. The ARAnchor is used to
> place a virtual ModelEntity (in this case, a cube) in the augmented
> reality space.
>
> The transform matrix (simd_float4x4) in
> AnchoringComponent(.world(transform: transform)) is used to position
> and orient the ModelEntity relative to the AnchorEntity. The specific
> values in this transform matrix will affect the location and
> orientation of the model in the AR scene.
>
> As a result, when you run this code on a device with AR capabilities
> and move around, you should see a small cube appearing in your
> environment, positioned on the "closest" (most frontward) surface that
> ARKit is able to detect.

Part 1

SwiftUI does not refresh UIViewRepresentable types in the same way as regular SwiftUI views. In other words, when a state is toggled, SwiftUI re-renders its body, but it doesn't do the same for the UIViewRepresentable types. This is why your ARView is not refreshing.

You'll need to handle the changes directly in the ARView instance and manually trigger updates there when necessary.

1. It seems like you're creating a new AnchorEntity every time you find
   a new anchor. It's probably better to keep track of a single
   AnchorEntity instance and update its anchor when needed.
2. When attaching the model to the anchor, you should add the anchor to
   the ARView's scene.anchors instead of setting the refreshToggle.
3. You should also remove the old anchor from the ARView's scene when a
   new closest anchor is found.

...

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

        // existing code...
    
        // Create a single AnchorEntity instance
        var anchorEntity: AnchorEntity?
    
        for anchor in anchors {
            // existing code...
    
            if let closestAnchor = closestAnchor {
                // If an anchorEntity already exists, remove it from the ARView's scene
                if let existingAnchor = anchorEntity {
                    existingAnchor.removeFromParent()
                }
    
                // Create a new AnchorEntity and attach the model to it
                anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: closestAnchor)
                anchorEntity?.children.append(model)
    
                // Add the anchorEntity to the ARView's scene
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    arView.scene.anchors.append(anchorEntity!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now we update ARView directly whenever a new closest anchor is found. Instead of trying to refresh the whole `ARViewContainer`, it only updates the *relevant* part of the AR scene, which is more efficient and also avoids potential issues with SwiftUI not refreshing the `UIViewRepresentable` type.

Comment: I think your approach is correct. I had to use a `@Binding var arView: ARView?` to get access to the `arView` defined in the `ARViewContainer`. However, the virtual object is still invisible. Any idea what is still missing?

Comment: There's many reasons this could happen. If all else fails, you might want to try creating a very simple object, like a colored sphere, and attaching that to the anchor instead. If the sphere appears, then you know the issue lies somewhere with your original model.

You may also want to print out the status of the `ARSession` to make sure it's running as expected. A status of .normal will confirm that the session is running normally. If you're seeing another status, such as .limited, that could explain why your anchors are not appearing

Comment: If that does not work please post more of your code in a new question or add to this question.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Another possibility is the rendering order of the entities in your scene. In some cases, if the mesh and the model are located at the same position, the model could be occluded by the mesh, making it invisible.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Trying to find your contact info so we can further discuss the problem since I have other theories but having trouble.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your efforts. In the debugger console, I found a property `_state = 1` of the `arView` session. I hope this is `.normal`. I also disabled `sceneUnderstanding.options .occlusion` but this did not help. I published my test project on GitHub <https://github.com/zeh4soft/BasicAR>. If you had time to have a look, this would be great!

Comment: I found a bug: I sorted anchors using y instead of z. Corrected on GitHub. Unfortunately, the virtual object is still not rendered.

Comment: Since I posted the code in my answer, I made the GitHub repo private.